# Service Trace Viewer not displaying everything

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have an IIS hosted WCF service that I want to trace using the Service Trace Viewer. 
Here is the configuration in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<!-- ... -->
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All,Information,ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="C:\Program Files\Archimede\TurniArc\log\web_tracelog.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
   <trace autoflush="true" /> 
</system.diagnostics>
<!-- ... -->
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="10000"
         logEntireMessage="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
            <filters>
                <clear/>
            </filters>
        </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
<!-- ... -->
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am only scratching its surface, there are many options and features I have yet to understand, but I really can't explain certain things that bug me:

1. when a method of the web service gets called, I manage to find the raw response envelope I send back, but most of the times the request just doesn't seem to be there
2. worse than that, sometimes the .svclog file doesn't even contain any activity, when I'm 100% sure that some calls have been handled, even after iisreset

Why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and searched for suggestions, but didn't found anything directly usable. After some experimentation i found this:

i needed to increase the max. size for the messages, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="false"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65000">
       <filters>
         <clear/>
       </filters>
    </messageLogging>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

if your trace log is empty it may be a problem with flushing. When debugging on my wn machine, i had to stop the asp.net development server.